# Import contacts and automatically validate contacts in Infusionsoft

Tags: infusionsoft

I'm starting to use Infusionsoft and I want to import all the contacts I have but I would like to automatically validate all the emails instead of sending a confirmation email.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import contacts without sending confirmation email. The drawback with that is you won't be able to add them in campaign or broadcasts.